# Serving Static Files in Express not working

Tags: express, static

**I want:**

I want to access static files in /uploads folder in the root of my project by visiting the URL (http://localhost:4002/uploads/test.jpg)

**The issue:**

I am unable to access static files in uploads folder. Visiting the URL (http://localhost:4002/uploads/test.jpg) gives: Cannot GET /uploads/test.jpg

According to a tutorial I follow and to official docs it should work the way I have implemented it...

**I have tried three methods:**

```
  app.use(express.static('uploads'))
  app.use('/uploads', express.static('uploads')) 
  app.use('/uploads', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'uploads')))
```

GitHub Repo [Link](https://github.com/welschmoor/instaclone-nc)

[Documentation Link](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html)
[image]

Comment: Where is the actual `test.jpg` file that you want to serve?  In your repository, you show a `tests.jpg` in the `uploads` directly, but NOT a `test.jpg` file.

Comment: Also, what are these other methods such as `server.applyMiddleware()` and `server.start()`.  These aren't Express code so we have no idea what they do.  Perhaps your `app.use()` statements are not even connected to an actual running server?

Comment: Hello, jfriend00, test.jpg is inside upload folder in root of project. See github repo, the files are there. The server works perfectly (it's an apollo-graphql-express server). It was just a typo with test and tests, I tried many different files with no luck.

Comment: In your github repo, there's a `tests.jpg`, but NOT a `test.jpg` in the `uploads` folder.

Comment: If you change the URL to match the filename that actually exists in the `uploads` folder, then `app.use('/uploads', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'uploads')))` should work with `http://localhost:4002/uploads/tests.jpg` .

Comment: This was indeed the error, thanks, and I tried many files with app.use(express.static('uploads')) which none of them work. Thank you very much. I actually copied filenames (F2) not sure how the typo creeped in. Thank you, and a low bow

Comment: Also, please see [Why not upload images of code when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557).  But kudos for including a link to your repo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your github repo, there's a `tests.jpg`, but NOT a `test.jpg` in the uploads folder so thus the URL in your question `http://localhost:4002/uploads/test.jpg` refers to a file that is not present in the `uploads` directory .

If you change the URL to match the filename that actually exists in the `uploads` folder, then

```
app.use('/uploads', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'uploads')));
```

should work with the URL

```
http://localhost:4002/uploads/tests.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I was also stuck at the same problem for a long time and then I got the result i.e., when you are serving any folder and try to get the file through link then you should take care of the following :-

> You tried this many ways, try it again with some changes while accessing

```
  app.use(express.static('uploads'))
  app.use('/uploads', express.static('uploads')) 
  app.use('/uploads', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'uploads')))
```

This error will for sure through if you try to access the file as below :

```
Cannot GET /uploads/test.jpg
```

But you can resolve it by doing this

```
localhost:${port}/test.jpg
```

directly. Because the uploads folder will be by default in the GET URL, now you just need to mention the foldername/filename after localhost:port if any otherwise just call

```
localhost:port/test.jpg
```